# How to access struct values inside of another struct in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I currently have

```
struct cellData {
    var opened = Bool()
    var title = String()
    var iconName = String()
    var sectionData = [Any]()
}

struct SectionData {
    var subTitle: String
    var iconName: String
}
```

And in another function I call:

```
let test = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]

print(test)
```

Which outputs:

```
SectionData(subTitle: "Terms", iconName: "")
```

How do I access the subTitle value because doing test.subTitle throws the following error:

Value of type 'Any' has no member 'subTitle'

Answer (score 6):

This is because, in your line `var sectionData = [Any]()`, you have defined the type as `Any`. So when you access it via `tableViewData[indexPath.section]`, you get back the value as `Any`.

You should change `var sectionData = [Any]()` to `var sectionData = [SectionData]()`

Otherwise, once you get the value from `tableViewData[indexPath.section]`, you can convert to `SectionData` and then access the value.

Comment: @JasonBiondo if this answer resolved your issue (the right answer), please don't forget to accept it (green tick it).

Answer (score 0):

Change your `sectionData` array to an array of SectionData like so: `var sectionData = [SectionData]()`. Once you do this, you'll able to access it by calling: `tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex].subTitle`